# Showing wrong output while reading from file in java

Tags: java

Running this program shows the wrong output. My file "values.txt" contains `45678` and the output
after running the program is `00000`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class array{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        final int SIZE = 6;
        int[] numbers = new int[SIZE];
        int index = 0;
        File fl = new File("values.txt");
        Scanner ab = new Scanner(fl);
        while(ab.hasNext() && index < numbers.length)
        {
            numbers[index] = ab.nextInt();
            index++;
            System.out.println(numbers[index]);
        }
        ab.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: replace your while loop with while(ab.hasNext() && index<numbers.length)
        {
            numbers[index]=ab.nextInt();
            System.out.println(numbers[index]);
            index++;
        }

Answer (score 4):

You first assign to `numbers[index]` then increase `index` and output `numbers[index]` (for the next empty value).

Swap `index++` and `System.out` calls.

Answer (score 4):

Move `index++` to after the `System.out.println` call.

At the moment you're always outputting an unassigned value of `numbers`. (In Java every element in an array of `int` is initialised to zero).

An alternative would be to discard `index++;` entirely and write `System.out.println(numbers[index++]);`. I personally find that clearer.